# Javascript open new window address bar still showing

Tags: javascript, address-bar

Im having a problem where I click a link and it opens a new window in fullscreen mode, but the address bar is still showing which I don't want it to. Here is the code I have:

```
function fullScreen(theURL) {
   window.open(theURL, '', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=1, toolbar=0, location=no');
}
```

Same problem in latest FF and IE8...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is no longer possible to do this in modern browsers for security reasons (people trying to trick users into thinking a web page is something its not).

Comment: Yes, this is to avoid phishing popups.